# How to import socket.io.client into Angular2 app using Webpack

Tags: socket.io, angular, webpack

I'm trying to import socket.io.client into an Angular2 app using webpack and I'm having no luck.

> 'socket.io-client' has no default export

I have done the following...

```
npm install socket.io-client --save
typings install socket.io-client --save --ambient
```

**vendor.ts**

```
import 'socket.io-client';
```

**webpack.config**

```
resolve : {
  alias: {
    'socket.io-client': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'socket.io-client', 'socket.io.js')
}}

module :{
  noParse: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'socket.io-client'),
  ...
}
entry: {
    'vendor':    './src/vendor.ts',
    ...
  }
```

**component.ts**

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
```

Webpack Error

Comment: In vendor.ts and component.ts change imports to `import * as io from 'socket.io-client';`

Comment: You were right but I didn't need the changes to the vendor.ts or webpack.config. Just;
`npm install socket.io-client --save; 
typings install socket.io-client --save --ambient; 
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';` in the component